# Call To Service Function: Not Populating Scope On First Execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am refactoring some angularjs code to make the controller leaner and move some logic into a service.

**Old Code** This works OK.

In Controller...

```
var firmSearchRequest = {
    type : "ByDate",
    startDate : $scope.startDate,
    endDate : $scope.endDate
};

firmService.getFirms(firmSearchRequest).then(function(response) {           
    firmService.appendFirmList(response.data);          
    $scope.firmList = firmService.getFirmList();
});
```

In Service...

```
var firmList = [];

    this.getFirms = function(firmSearchRequest) {
        return httpService.putForResponse('firms/search', firmSearchRequest);
    };


    this.appendFirmList = function(newfirmList){
        firmList = firmList.concat(newfirmList);
    }


    this.getFirmList = function() {
        return firmList;
    };
```

**Refactored Code** Does not work as expected

In Controller...

```
var firmSearchRequest = {
    type : "ByDate",
    startDate : $scope.startDate,
    endDate : $scope.endDate
};

$scope.firmList = firmService.appendFirmListByDate(firmSearchRequest);
```

In Service...

```
var firmList = [];

    this.appendFirmListByDate = function(firmSearchRequest){

        this.getFirms(firmSearchRequest).then(function(response) {          
            firmList = firmList.concat(response.data);
        });

        return firmList;

    };

    this.getFirms = function(firmSearchRequest) {
        return httpService.putForResponse('firms/search', firmSearchRequest);
    };
```

**Unexpected Behavior**

For the refactored code, when I click the button that executes the code above, I receive no console error but the `$scope.firmList` is empty. When I click the button a second time for a second execution, `$scope.firmList` is correctly populated.

Why is the first execution not working correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller

```
$scope.firmList = firmService.appendFirmListByDate(firmSearchRequest);
```

here the function **firmService.appendFirmListByDate()** is a simple function and will run synchronously so the value will be returned immediately so the returned value in this case is empty array named **firmList**

so the question arises why you get the correct list when you click the button for second time.

- when you clicked the button for second time then the value inside the array **var firmList = []** was inserted because of the promise that ran for the first time and it was

  ```
  this.getFirms(firmSearchRequest).then(function(response) {          
      firmList = firmList.concat(response.data);
  });
  ```
- when you clicked the button second time then the function still ran synchronously and you got the value that was populated in first step.

**Note- so every time you are getting a value that was populated by the promise in the last step.**

**Important point**

- you can't refactor your code in this way
- making a thin controller doesn't mean removing the promise out of it. It means the the business logic should not be there. so your promises should be inside service which should return a promise to the controller and data manipulation etc. should done inside the service

**Returning a promise from service**

```
this.appendFirmListByDate = function(firmSearchRequest){
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        //if firmList contains data then just return it
        if(firmList.length!==0){
               resolve(firmList);
         }else{
            this.getFirms(firmSearchRequest).then(function(response) {          
               firmList = firmList.concat(response.data);
               resolve(firmList);
            }).catch(function(error){
                  reject(error);
            });
        }

    });
};
```

Comment: Many thanks for your comprehensive answer. I did look at returning a promise to my controller but I kept getting a `then is not a function` error. I gave up after a few hours of trying. My goal is to have `$scope.firmList = firmService.appendFirmList(response.data);` in the controller so that I don't have to make a second call to the service just to update the scope, as you can see in the older version (if possible). I don't usually ask this, but I'd really appreciate if you could demonstrate how to achieve by incorporating promises with my code above. Thanks!

Comment: @John i have edited the code you just call the function as a promise in your controller

Comment: Thanks @selftaught91 I really appreciate it

Comment: @JohnSteed Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

aren't you attempting to return firmList before (and technically regardless of whether ) the promise is completed?

You should put the return inside the promise, or maybe return the promise.

Comment: sorry if you return the value  **return firmList** inside promise it will not work because **firmService.appendFirmListByDate(firmSearchRequest)** is a synchronous function and it will return the value immediately and then there will be no effect of value being returned inside the promise

Comment: makes sense, would you suggest returning the promise?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `callaback` function

**Service**

```
this.appendFirmListByDate = function(firmSearchRequest, fct){
    this.getFirms(firmSearchRequest).then(function(response) {          
        fct(firmList.concat(response.data);)
    });
};
```

**Controller**

```
firmService.appendFirmListByDate(firmSearchRequest, function(result){
    $scope.firmList = result;
});
```